# Pinch-Zoom with Swing and OpenJDK

Tags: java, swing, pinchzoom

With Oracle-JDK, a pinch-zoom is interpreted as mouse wheel event, which can be used to control the zoom action. With OpenJDK (12 and later), the mouse wheel event is no longer fired.

On JavaFX there are new Zoom-Events, but JavaFX is not an option at the moment.

There is a bug report on this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8226225
Does anyone know a workaround for pinch-zoom on Swing components using OpenJDK?

Comment: OpenJDK is not the only JDK available. There may be a JDK that does not have this bug. Refer to [List of Java virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines)

Comment: Thank you @Abra. I will give it a try!